# how to display elements of checked radio when element are (display: none)

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, display, checked

I'm going to make a checkbox with the values ​​inside it.
but if a default radio is selected, the values ​​inside it will not be displayed and must be clicked.

I know a solution using `#IDcheck:checked~#IDelement{display:block}` in `style`. but it faces many limitations.

so is there a script code command to solve this problem.

for example solve the problem of not displaying the pre-checked radio-check in the following code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<style>
    .box{
        display: none;
    }

</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
        var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
        $(".box").not(targetBox).hide();
        $(targetBox).show();
    });
});
</script>
<label>
          <!-- pre checked here -->
       <input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="red" checked> red</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="green"> green</label>

          <!-- don't show -->
    <div id="idr" class="red box">You have selected red</div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected green</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using following way using Javascript. No `Jquery` needed

```js
function handleSelection(e) {
      const el = document.getElementById(e.value)
      
      const list = document.querySelectorAll('.box')
      
      list.forEach(i=> {
        i.classList.remove('show')
        i.classList.add('hide')
       }
      )
      
      el.classList.remove('hide')
      el.classList.add('show')
    }
```

```css
 body {
    font-family: sans-serif;  
    }
    
    .box {
      padding-top: 16px;
    }
    
    .show {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .hide {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
  
  <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="red" checked onclick="handleSelection(this)"> red</label>
  <input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="green" onclick="handleSelection(this)"> green</label>

    <div id="red" class="box show">You have selected red</div>
    <div id='green' class="box hide">You have selected green</div>
```